# Getting an error while trying to execute MYSQL stored procedure in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I have created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Toy
(Toy_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 Toy_Name VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
 Toy_Price NUMERIC NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (Toy_ID)
)
```

and then I inserted the values in toy table:

```
INSERT INTO Toy (Toy_Name,Toy_Price)
VALUES ('Naruto',25.00);
INSERT INTO Toy (Toy_Name,Toy_Price)
VALUES ('Goku',25.00);
INSERT INTO Toy (Toy_Name,Toy_Price)
VALUES ('Luffy',25.00);
```

and then I typed the following stored procedure in SQL window in phpmyadmin:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE searchtoy (IN toy_no INT)
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM Toy
WHERE Toy_ID = toy_no;
END;
```

The stored procedure has been created successfully.

Then I tried to execute the stored procedure in the SQL window and I also have added // in the Delimiter text box:

```
CALL searchtoy(1);
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Error
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

Unexpected token. (near ";" at position 17)
SQL query:

CALL searchtoy(1);

MySQL said: Documentation

#1305 - PROCEDURE demo.searchtoy does not exist
```

Despite the stored procedure being created successfully, it is still showing that the stored procedure does not exist.

Where did I go wrong ?
It would be really helpful if the solution code is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is looking for `searchtoy` in `demo` schema. check the schema in which you have created your function